# NGINX: Subdomain to subdirectory without redirection

Tags: redirect, nginx, subdomain, subdirectory

I need to convert sub domain to sub directory like abc.example.com => example.com/abc , I read the nginx forum and tried proxy pass with config as follows:

abc.example.com nginx config file:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://example.com/abc;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

example.com nginx config file:

```
upstream example { 
    least_conn;
    server ip_addr_1:port;
    server ip_addr_2:port;
}
server {
    listen    80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com
    root /var/www/test/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    ssl on;    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

The config file works, but it opens up blank page with console error as:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I realize that for calls like /api and /css, it has be to made as follows

```
example.com/api
example.com/css
```

and not with abc.example.com:

```
abc.example.com/api
abc.example.com/css
```

So after I changed the config file as described above, I get the home page of example.com if I try to open abc.example.com instead of getting example.com/abc.

**Overall**: Need help to get subdomains mapped to subpath / subdirectory without chaning the URL (redirection off) and /api and /css should be called at top(root) domain.

Thank you for reading the entire question with patience andto help with the problem!

**P.S.**
I modified the config as follows: [paste](http://pastebin.com/aqLXCxJX). We are able to get the mapping with URI retained as abc.example.com but can't get rid of /abc. So, the URI appearing is abc.example.com/abc, instead we need it to be just abc.example.com. In short, need help to get rid of that extra **/abc** from the URL appearing to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
server {
  server_name abc.example.com;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://example/abc/;
     proxy_set_header Host "example.com";
  }
  location /api {
     proxy_pass http://example;
     proxy_set_header Host "example.com";
  }
  location /css {
     proxy_pass http://example;
     proxy_set_header Host "example.com";
  }
}
```

Comment: However, I must add that you probably want to server the /css statically from nginx.

Comment: Thanks to answer! I tried with the config you mentioned. The link abc.example.com still takes me to home page of example.com instead of example.com/abc which is what we had passed in **proxy-pass**.

Comment: it must be your upstream configuration that is causing the issues; you may wish to use the optional http://nginx.org/r/sub_filter module to ensure all references are changed

Comment: I fixed the upstream and proxy_pass issue, and It's able to render abc.example.com but with URI => abc.example.com/abc. Sub_filter was also of no use. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @manishrw, you must be using something else than what's provided in the answer.  it should work without any extra `/abc` when you load abc.example.com.

Comment: This is my new config file http://pastebin.com/aqLXCxJX . It's opening with /abc which i don't want.

Comment: I don't see why it would do that based on the config, probably the problem is with the app itself; BTW, you'd want `sub_filter_once off; sub_filter /abc/ /;` instead of what you have.